# Can't retrieve the spring application context in a multimodule springboot project / EntityManagerFactory can not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, component-scan, spring-boot-configuration

I have a multimodule springboot project. Here is the architecture:
[image]

The class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` is in the top module (webservice). When I run integration test from this top module using `@SpringBootTest`in my test classes, it works fine.

But now I'd like to run integration test from the business module. `@SpringBootTest` only doesn't work anymore because no config class can be found in the business module. So I created a config class in the business module:

```java
package com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.business.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.berthoud.p7")
public class TestContextConfiguration {
}
```

And  in my test classes, I pointed to this config class, like this :

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestContextConfiguration.class)
public class BookResearchIT {
//my tests...
}
```

Doing so, I was hopping that Spring would add to the context all the beans declared in the package com.berthoud.p7 and its subfolders. Indeed, when I autowire spring beans in my test classes it now looks fine (IntelliJ doesnt tell anymore that the `@autowired`beans cannot be autowired): 
[image]

But nevertheless, when I run my tests, Spring fails to load the application context :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bookReferenceDAO in com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.business.BookResearchManager required a bean of type 'com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.consumer.contract.BookReferenceDAO' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.consumer.contract.BookReferenceDAO' in your configuration.
```

I don't understand this. Here is how I declared the beans concerned :

```java
package com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.business;

@Service
public class BookResearchManager {

    @Autowired
    BookReferenceDAO bookReferenceDAO;

    @Autowired
    LibrairyDAO librairyDAO;

    @Autowired
    BookDAO bookDAO;
```

```java
package com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.consumer.contract;

public interface BookReferenceDAO {
// method signatures
}
```

```java
package com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.consumer.repositories.SpringDataJPA;

public interface BookReferenceRepository extends CrudRepository<BookReference, Integer>, BookReferenceDAO {
```

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** after changing my config class like this :

```java
package com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.business.config;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.consumer")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp")
public class TestContextConfiguration {
}
```

I now have a different error :

```
Field bookReferenceDAO in com.berthoud.p7.webserviceapp.business.BookResearchManager required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

Comment: I think you are missing @EnableJpaRepositories annotation.

Comment: Does the application run at all? I would say you need to annotate your BookResearchManager with @Component

Comment: the application runs perfectly, and as I wrote I can run the tests from the top module.

Comment: Edit : BookResearchManager was always annotated with @service in my code